# Angular - Why use $resource over $http for RESTful services

Tags: angularjs

I have been reading that to call http, you need to call $http service, and REST services are contained in http, so to call REST it's better to call $resource as they deal better with REST services, and this is what I wanted to do at work, until this guy told me let's just use $http for REST as he does that in all his projects, I couldn't tell him why to really use $resource over $http except that I have just read it's better, but can someone tell me why is it better?

Comment: It's not "better". It' a layer of abstraction above. I also don't like this additional layer of abstraction. I find my code is harder to write and understand with $resource. Voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: It's not opinion based. Documentation in AngularJS SAYS use $resource for REST services as it would be easier to deal with REST using $resource, the question is HOW is it easier? Where's the opinion based?

Comment: Where does it say that? All I see in the docs is *"For a higher level of abstraction, please check out the $resource service."* (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Whether you find it easier or not depends on how much you know about $http, how much you know about $resource, how your REST services are designed, and your own opinion. Mine is that using $http directly is easier, and leads to easier to understand code.

Comment: Please check out the documentation for $resource as it says: 
"A factory which creates a resource object that lets you interact with RESTful server-side data sources.

The returned resource object has action methods which provide high-level behaviors without the need to interact with the low level $http service."  and it's implicit everywhere that Angualr recommends using $resource when dealing with REST services, isn't this why they created $resource in the first place? Then it's not opinion based question, it's why angular even created $resource and why it recommends it for REST.